# Why VRCapture can't record the samples of openvr

Tags: virtual-reality, openvr

Help! Why VRCapture can't record the samples of openvr(I have tested openvr-1.8.19 and openvr-v.1.6.10b version)? The result video is black. But works well with other VR games I got from steams.Thank you.

My computer:
AMD Ryzen 7 1700X Eight-core
16G
Geforce GTX 1070 Ti
Windows 10 Pro 64
Visual Studio 2017 Community with windows SDK 10.0.17763.0

Comment: I found old openvr SDK works.